Singular values as min max of absolute rayleigh quotient
Consider a real symmetric matrix M, satisfying $\mathbf{1}^\intercal M = \mathbf{1}^\intercal$ having eigenvalues $1=\lambda_1 \gt\|\lambda_2\| \geq \|\lambda_3\| .... \geq \| \lambda_n\|$, then can I use Rayleigh quotient to find the singular values like the following:
$\|\lambda_2\| = \max_{x \perp \mathbf{1}} \frac{\| x^\intercal M x\
|}{\|x^\intercal x\|}$

Check the min-max theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem
